# Mathematical Induction Problem with Fraction

Tags: calculus, algebra-precalculus, induction

$$(3n-2)^2=\frac{n(6n^2-3n-1)}{2}$$

I can't seem to solve it out to the point where I can prove it right or wrong. I always hit some sort of roadblock where I don't have enough info to prove it wrong, but I can't move farther to prove it right. Help?

Comment: What happens if you plug in $n=2$?

Comment: It's not true; for $n=2$, the LHS is $4$ while the RHS is $17$.

Comment: Is there an error in your post? As @rogerl mentioned, this fails for $n=2$ (and others)

Comment: So that would prove it wrong then @rogerl? Plugging in 2 for n? I was taught to plug in (n+1). I suppose plugging in n=2 does the same job.

Comment: Showing that if it's true for $n+1$ if it's true for $n$ is how to prove it's true with induction; however, it is not the method to prove it false. All you need is one counterexample to prove something wrong.

Comment: Probably a stupid question, but @Alqatrkapa, if I prove it false with n=2, does that apply to the induction as well?

Comment: Explain a little more what you mean about "applying to the induction".

Comment: I'm not sure exactly what you mean. The purpose of induction is to prove that a statement holds *for all $n$*. If you find an $n$ for which it does not hold, then clearly you can't prove it true for all $n$.

Comment: @Alqatrkapa, I meant does it prove the induction wrong too, but rogerl answered that for me. Thanks guys, I get it now (and feel a little stupid too lol)

Comment: @Kekker: Knowledge comes with experience. Don't worry at all that you may not know as much as anyone else on MSE: it will come with time

Comment: @Alqatrkapa alright thanks. I appreciate your help, I should probably come by here more often.

Comment: @Kekker please don't change the question substantively after it's been asked. It makes all the existing answers invalid.

Comment: And by the way, this equation is also not valid; $n=2$ is still a counterexample.

Comment: Oh shoot I did have an error in my original problem. I edited it, the (3n-2) was supposed to be squared. It 's still false

Comment: sorry, @rogerl I had an error that I hadn't noticed. I changed it, then checked n=2 before commenting.

Comment: @Kekker And what is you result for n=2 ?

Comment: 16=17, why @calculus

Comment: @Kekker: So since $16 \neq 17$ does this equation hold for $n=2$? And what can you say about *all* $n$?

Comment: @Kekker I just wanted to be sure, that you don´t try something with induction.

Comment: @user667648 not all will be true. That had already been answered, but thank you.

Answer (score 2):

I think the problem is misstated.  You might have better luck proving (by induction) that for all $n\ge 1$, $\sum_{k=1}^n (3k-2)^2 = \frac{n(6n^2-3n-1)}{2}$

Answer (score 0):

As stated, this can't possibly be true for infinitely many $n$. The LHS is a quadratic polynomial but the RHS is a cubic. This means you have a cubic equation, so it can be satisfied by at most three distinct values of $n$.